# Another way to get files owner than from advapi32 on windows

Tags: go, optimization, window

I'm working on a golang script who get fileInfo and owner from every file using go 1.10.3 on a 32 bit windows.
My script work well but im facing a problem.
The library advapi32 and more specificly GetNamedSecurityInfoW and LookupAccountNameW functions take around 1 millisecond since I've got a big amount of files the "scan" is obviously too long.
I just wanted too now if there's another way to do it faster ?
I'm open on any suggetion or help Thanks.

Comment: Spawn multiple Go routines and see if that makes it faster. Otherwise, how do you call the API? Do you use syscall, LazyDLL or a library? Show us the code.

Comment: could you please provide the code to get the AccountName? via GetNamedSecurityInfoW and LookupAccountNameW - Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you gonutz i managed to make it quite faster with goroutine, I aproach 2 500 000 files every 22minute. And my algorythm is still not optimised.